# PHP's get_browser vs WURFL - which yields more accurate result

Tags: php, wurfl

Currently, I plan to obtain 3 browser information at server side, based on user agent string

1. Browser name
2. Major version
3. Minor version

I realize there are 2 popular solution to do so

1. [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)
2. PHP get_browser (which makes use of [browscap.ini](https://browscap.org/))

Right now, We prefer correctness over execution speed.

Has anyone experience both solution before? I was wondering, which solution yields more accurate result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the CTO of ScientiaMobile, the company that delivers WURFL.

I am not familiar with the implementation of PHP get_browser, but I would be very surprised if it came close to the level of accuracy that WURFL can provide (including the `advertised_browser*` virtual capabilities).

At ScientiaMobile we have a fully-fledged team that is constantly looking at the user-agent space and is fine tuning the WURFL data and API to correctly reflect the properties of devices and browsers (and respective versions).

Of course, WURFL is not a free solution (albeit we make evaluation version of the OnSite APIs available to the general public).

Comment: Great to see someone from WURFL company :)